Announcing an Election for 2024
Summary: Coffee Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for an election on September 24.
The timeline:

On September 17, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.

Starting on September 24, users can {nominate themselves](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/election/3). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.

On October 1, if there are 2 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination.)

If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on October 9 (or October 16, if we need to extend the nomination period).


If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.
